# How to find my Database Host in my phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database on my server. How can I find my database host to install WordPress.

Comment: just google for phpMyAdmin config

Comment: I have headache after reading your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the installation process, then your input field for the database host is "localhost" :)